# Angular: when editing an user profile, the app navigates to home page

Tags: angular, firebase, navigation

I have two components: home and admin. In the home component, I can create, delete and edit posts. On the admin I do exacly the same but with another collection of the database (I'm using FireBase). But the behaviour I dont understand: when I click to edit an employee, the router navigates to home. And when editing the posts (home), everything looks fine. The code from both components is pratically the same:

Admin.ts

```
user: Users[];
  show = false;
  employees: Users = {
    id: '',
    userName: '',
    phone: '',
    role: '',
    name: '',
  };

  edit = false;
  employeeToEdit: Users;

  constructor(private userService: UsersService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.user = data;
      console.log(this.user);
    });
  }

  addEmployee(item: Users) {
    if (this.employees.userName !== "" && this.employees.phone !== "" && this.employees.role !== ""
      && this.employees.name !==  "") {
      this.userService.addUser(this.employees);
    }else{
     this.show = true;
      setTimeout(function () {
        this.show = false;
      }.bind(this), 3000);
    }
    }


  deleteItem(event, item: Users) {
    this.clearStateE();
    this.userService.deleteUser(item);
  }

  editEmployee(event, item: Users) {
    this.edit = true;
    this.employeeToEdit = item;
  }

  updateItem(item: Users) {
    this.userService.updateUser(item);
    this.clearStateE();
  }

  clearStateE() {
    this.edit = false;
    this.employeeToEdit = null;
  }
```

The HTML:

```
<h1>Employees</h1>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <span class="card-title">Add Item</span>
    <form (ngSubmit)="addEmployee()" class="col s6">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Add Description" [(ngModel)]="employees.userName" name="description">

        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Add Description" [(ngModel)]="employees.phone" name="description">

        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Add Description" [(ngModel)]="employees.role" name="description">

        </div>

      <div *ngIf="show" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        All fields are requiered
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


<ul *ngFor="let employee of user" class="collection">
  <li class="collection-item"><strong>{{employee.name}}: </strong> {{employee.phone}} <a href="#" class="secondary-content">
<i (click)="editEmployee($event, employee)" class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
<i *ngIf="edit && employeeToEdit.id == employee.id" (click)="clearStateE()" class="fa fa-compress"></i>
    </a>

<div *ngIf="edit && employeeToEdit.id == employee.id">
      <form (ngSubmit)="updateItem(employee)">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add Title" [(ngModel)]="employee.name" name="title">
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add Description" [(ngModel)]="employee.phone" name="description">
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add Date" [(ngModel)]="employee.userName" name="description">
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Update Item" class="btn orange">
          <button (click)="deleteItem($event, employee)" class="btn red">Delete Item</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Routing.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './components/admin/admin.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: HomeComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Other thing that happens when navigating between both components is that the data retrieved is no longer there (only appears the list when I insert another one). Can someone help me out?

EDIT: I tried something like this, but still doesnt work like is suposed to

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "admin",
    component: AdminComponent
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "home"

  },
  {
    path: "home",
    component: HomeComponent

  }
```

Comment: Can you comment the path: '**' ? You will probably have explicit error on your browser console that explain what append. If console is cleared, don't forget to put it to "preserve log".

Comment: `Error: Invalid configuration of route ''. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren` So this means that I have to add one of these propreties?

Comment: Do you have this last error when you are on '/admin' and you submit ?

Comment: @Gilsdav, I've updated the post

Comment: First `"**"` path must be last route because it cancel every routes after it.
To have correct routes use this : `const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent
    pathMatch: "full"
  }
  {
    path: "admin",
    component: AdminComponent
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "/"
  }
];`

Comment: An other point with your delete button. Default behavior of button in form is `submit`. So don't forget to add type attribute `type="button"`. Your button will handle click and submit if you don't do that.

Comment: @Gilsdav, I've set like this `const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "admin",
    component: AdminComponent
  },
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/",
    pathMatch: "full"
  }
];` but the behaviour persists

Comment: Your last path must be `"**"` (not `""`) and must not have pathMatch. But it doesn't seams to be the problem.
Is it possible you have a <form> in an other <form> ?

Comment: The full HTML is ther, of this component. There two forms but they are separated. Can it be a conflict with the other component?

Comment: Ok so the problem I'm thinking about can only happen if you have a <form> tag in your app.component. Probably not your error. Can you try to add `#editform="ngForm"` on your form ? `ngSubmit` is an output of this directive.

Comment: My app.component: `<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="container nav-dist">

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>` and I added `   <form #editform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="updateItem(employee)">`, but the problem remains...

Comment: To check if it's a form issue can you replace your input submit by `<button type="button" (click)="updateItem(employee)" class="btn orange">Update Item</button>` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184940/discussion-between-mellville-and-gilsdav).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `<a href="#" class="secondary-content">` around your "edit" button that conflict with your `(click)`.
In fact that `#` link will redirect to the "home" page.